# Linux BLE Gatt server program is unable to retrieve dbus org.bluez object when run as a service

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, systemd, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

Linux BLE Gatt server program is unable to retrieve dbus org.bluez object when run as a service. The programs works fine when I run the program using the terminal as root but it fails when I try to have the program run as a service.

Here is my systemd testproj.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Start BLE Gatt Server

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=com.testproj
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/ble_gatt_server
ExecStart=/home/root/ble_gatt_server/standalone
User=root


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also here are my permission files for dbus
testproj.conf content is below

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>
  <policy at_console="true">
    <allow own="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>
  <policy group="lp">
    <allow own="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>
  <policy context="default">
    <allow own="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="com.testproj"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Also here are my permission files for dbus
bluetooth.conf content is below

```
<!-- This configuration file specifies the required security policies
     for Bluetooth core daemon to work. -->

<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>

  <!-- ../system.conf have denied everything, so we just punch some holes -->

  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Agent1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.ThermometerWatcher1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.AlertAgent1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Profile1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.HeartRateWatcher1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.CyclingSpeedWatcher1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattDescriptor1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>
  </policy>

  <policy at_console="true">
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- allow users of lp group (printing subsystem) to 
       communicate with bluetoothd -->
  <policy group="lp">
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>

  <policy context="default">
    <deny send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>

</busconfig>
```